# Can't login to QGIS Cloud plugin - QGIS 3.8 OSX 10.13

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I have a QGIS cloud account (free) and login via the web-page, so I think my access is fine.

But when I try to login via the QGISCloud plug-in via QGIS Desktop on my MacBook, I get Python Errors.

My QGIS desktop app detail:
[image: About my AGIS install - MacBook]

This is the Python Error log:

```
2019-10-24T06:32:47     WARNING    Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1317, in do_open
          encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
          File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1229, in request
          self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
          File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1275, in _send_request
          self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
          File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1224, in endheaders
          self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
          File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1016, in _send_output
          self.send(msg)
          File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 956, in send
          self.connect()
          File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/http/client.py", line 1392, in connect
          server_hostname=server_hostname)
          File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 412, in wrap_socket
          session=session
          File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 853, in _create
          self.do_handshake()
          File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/ssl.py", line 1117, in do_handshake
          self._sslobj.do_handshake()
         ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
         Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/Users/nikhenry/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgiscloud/qgiscloudplugindialog.py", line 292, in check_login
          version_info=self._version_info())
          File "/Users/nikhenry/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgiscloud/qgiscloudapi/qgiscloudapi.py", line 163, in check_login
          content = request.post(resource, data)
          File "/Users/nikhenry/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgiscloud/qgiscloudapi/qgiscloudapi.py", line 569, in post
          return self.request(resource, method='POST', data=data)
          File "/Users/nikhenry/Library/Application Support/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgiscloud/qgiscloudapi/qgiscloudapi.py", line 657, in request
          response = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
          File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 222, in urlopen
          return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
          File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 525, in open
          response = self._open(req, data)
          File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 543, in _open
          '_open', req)
          File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 503, in _call_chain
          result = func(*args)
          File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1360, in https_open
          context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
          File "/Applications/QGIS3.8.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/Current/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py", line 1319, in do_open
          raise URLError(err)
         urllib.error.URLError:
```

Comment: try to deactivate the proxy (if any) on your internet options, restart QGIS and try to connect again

Comment: J.R, thanks for your comment.  But not sure which internet options your referring to?  Router or QGIS.  
If you mean QGIS, I don't have any proxy setting.

Comment: At work I got similar error because we are behind a proxy (almost all QGIS plugin that need access to internet either don't work or throw an error if proxy is not deactivated), as we are on windows the setting is on the internet explorer "internet option" for macOS I don't know...

Comment: Thanks, I'll check all proxy setting...cheers

Comment: I have the same problem and can't manage to fix it... Have you found a solution?

Comment: Hi @diel, I haven’t tried On the Mac since my last comment. I have been able to use QgisCloud on a windows machine from the home office.